# IOS and Android home screen-like drag and drop menu?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On the iphone and Android home screen, you have icons that take up a "1x1" icon slot on the screen. You can also have widgets that can take up "2x1" icons, as well as "1x2," and "2x2." you can also pick these up, move them, and other objects (widgets and app icons) actively move to accommodate it.

In react native, is it possible to replicate this behavior (i.e. having views of different -- but proportional -- sizes that can move reactively to other objects being dragged around it)? How could this be done?

Comment: You can do this with `react-native-reanimated` and `react-native-gesture-handler`, but it is a very complex coding exercise. I can recommend for start William Candillons' tutorials.

Comment: What video of his could I go to specifically for a guide or good beginning point? @DánielBoros

Comment: I think this is a good start for your needs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-39OEXk_mWc&t=839s.